# Extract content data from HttpCllient's FormUrlEncodedContent

Tags: c#, post, httpclient, httpcontent

My content is:

```
var content = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"pickup_date", pickupDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")},
    {"to_city", "Victoria"},
    {"delivery_company", "4"},
    {"shop_refnum", parameters.Reference},
    {"dimension_side1", "20"},
    {"dimension_side2", "20"},
    {"dimension_side3", "20"},
    {"weight", "5"}
};

var httpContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(content);
```

How can I extract content from httpContent?

Comment: Extract content data for what use?

Comment: I'm logging all requests and responses.

Comment: I'm unit testing and want to verify the correct data is being posted

Answer (score 1):

I had to extract data information from the request in some unit tests that I wrote. Like the other answer stated, it is possible to use the following method in the `System.Net.Http` namespace (I'm using .NET Core 3.1):

```
public static Task<NameValueCollection> ReadAsFormDataAsync(this HttpContent content);
```

Applied to a `HttpContent` instance:

```
var content = request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();
var username = content.Result["username"];
```

Answer (score -2):

I found ReadAsFormDataAsync() method in System.Net.Http.Formatting:

```
NameValueCollection hcData = await httpContent.ReadAsFormDataAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Which .net/mvc versions are you using?